# How to stop wallpaper package hiding fancyhdr page numbers

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, backgrounds

When I use the `wallpaper` package to put a background behind a slide or document, and then use `fancyhdr` to try and paginate the document the page numbers dont show up. Am I doing something wrong, or is there a process for bringing the page numbers back? Thanks

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.7in, right=2in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{microtype,lipsum}
\geometry{letterpaper}
\usepackage{wallpaper} 
\ULCornerWallPaper{1.0}{pillar.pdf} \topmargin=0.25in \headheight=1in \headsep=0.1in 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Image for background of MWE attached below... [image: pillar.pdf]

Comment: `\topmargin=0.25in \headheight=1in \headsep=0.1in` is moving the text body down and so the page number is outside the page. Setup the layout only with `geometry` to get consistent and senseful values.

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer that solved the immediate problem and showed me why I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try the *xwatermark* package. Read the user guide.

```
\documentclass[final,showpagenos]{article}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
% Redefining \xwm@f@ncypagenos for a reason:
\robust@redef*\xwm@f@ncypagenos{%
  \def\pgn@textmark{%
    \begingroup
    \fboxrule\pgn@framerule\fboxsep\pgn@framesep\relax
    \pgn@format{\normalfont\pgn@style}%
    \endgroup
  }%
  \cptswitchtrue{xwm@fancy}%
  \xwm@textbox{pgn}%
  \cptswitchfalse{xwm@fancy}%
}
\watermarkpaths[.](/){{}{/graphics}} % your path may be different
\newwallpaper*[
  page=1,picangle=0,tile-xoffset=0pt,tile-yoffset=0pt,square-tiles,
  text-on-top-picture,boxalign=center,pic-bounding-box=125 551 340 668,
  picscale=.5,picfile=advanceknowledge,picfileext=pdf,
  %number-of-tiles=8,top-left
]{}

\fancypagenos[
  textalign         = center,
  show-page-numbers = true,
  show-on-page-one  = true,
  textcolor         = red,
  y-position        = -.42\paperheight,
  x-position        = 0,
  scale             = 2,
  angle             = 0,
  style             = \textsc{Page~\thepage~of~\pageref{xwmlastpage}}
]
\makeatother

\begin{document}
x
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AhmedMusa. This is a new and interesting approach for me. Why are you redefining \xwm@fancypagenos?

Comment: The command `\cptswitchtrue` used to be called `\switchtrue` in the *catoptions* package. The public version of *xwatermark* still uses the old command. So without redefinition, you'll get the error 'undefined control sequence ...'.